# variable scope in different files

Tags: php, scope, require

I'm trying to use a variable that is declared in file `f1`, in another file that is required by the same file.

Code in `f1`:

```
<?php

class Index extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index( $err = "" )
    {
        $err = "teeste";

        $this->view->render('index');
    }
}
?>
```

the line `$this->view->render('index');` is correct, I'm sure because the form is appearing correctly.

Code of the other file:

```
<form action='<?php echo URL . 'user';?>' method="POST">
<input type="text" name="login" maxlength="35"/>
<input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="35"/>
<input type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>

<?php 
echo $err; 
?>
```

I saw a lot of examples of this in the web but this one is not working even being simple.

Comment: Variables have function scope, files are irrelevant.

Comment: As @Barmar said, files are irrelevant here.  The issue is that `$err` exists only within the scope of the `index(..)` function, so you can't access it outside of that function, regardless of which file you try to do it in.

Comment: i already try to make $err a public property of the object and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all.

i solve through this way.

```
<?php

class Index extends Controller
{
    public $err;

    function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->view->error = "teeste";

        $this->view->render('index');
    }
}
?>
```

and

```
<form action='<?php echo URL . 'user';?>' method="POST">
<input type="text" name="login" maxlength="35"/>
<input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="35"/>
<input type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>

<?php 
echo $this->error; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a global variable. In the function:

```
public function index($err = "") {
    global $global_err;

    $global_err = "teeste";
    $this->view->render('index');
}
```

Then in your other file:

```
echo $global_err;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like codeigniter so I'm going to answer this how I see it

```
class Index extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
{   
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index( $err = "" )
{
    $data['err'] = "testee";

    $this->view->render('index', $data);
}
}
?>
```

and second file

```
<form action='<?php echo URL . 'user';?>' method="POST">
<input type="text" name="login" maxlength="35"/>
<input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="35"/>
<input type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>

<?php 
echo $err; 
?>
```